# Mongodb How to find two documents in a collection that the values of a property are the same

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The collection is like this:

```
{a: 1, c: true}, {a: 1, c: false}, {a: 1, c: false},
{a: 2, c: true}, {a: 2, c: false}, {a: 2, c: true}
```

Is there a query that can find two docs that has `{c: true}` and the value of `a` are the same? In the above example, it should return `{a:2, c: true}, {a:2, c: true}`.

Comment: It should return two document from above collection 1)`{a:2, c: true}, {a:2, c: true}` and 2) `{a:1, c: false}, {a:1, c: false}`?? Check here https://mongoplayground.net/p/fGNhy46UMZk

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, I just need the docs where c is true. so 2) should be filtered. In your solution, add a `{$match: {c: true}}` and remove `c: "$c"` in `$group` `_id` is exactly what I need! https://mongoplayground.net/p/vxg8fs7SBAO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "c": true } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "a": "$a" },
    "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": { "dataSize": { "$size": "$data" } } },
  { "$match": { "dataSize": 2 } },
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
])
```

Comment: `$addFields` and `$replaceRoot` are new knowledge good to know!